# Prevent quotes from being converted to HTML entities in twig ternary operator

Tags: twig

The following does **not** convert the quotes to HTML entities

```
{% for row in files %}
  <tr data-id="{{ row.id }}"><td>{{ row.name }}</td></tr>
{% endfor %}
```

The following **does** convert the quotes to HTML entities

```
{% for row in files %}
  <tr{{ row.id?' data-id="'~row.id~'"' }}><td>{{ row.name }}</td></tr>
{% endfor %}
```

How can I prevent quotes from being converted to HTML entities in a twig ternary operator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try the `|raw` filter (check out the [documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/raw.html)).
This is because in general, everything that twig prints out will be escaped to avoid things like cross-site-scripting. An exception is made for entirely static values like `{{ '<b>static value</b>' }}` which will not be escaped.

In  your case, the following should work:

```
{% for row in files %}
  <tr{{ (row.id?' data-id="'~row.id~'"')|raw }}><td>{{ row.name }}</td></tr>
{% endfor %}
```